# unable to install SP1 for my sharepoint designer, error "The expected version of the product was not found on the system"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, administration, configuration, installation, windows-server

I have downloaded SharePoint designer 2013 32-bit on my PC. My PC is is a Windows 7 64-bit with MS Office 32-bit.

Now I downloaded the SharePoint Designer from the following [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491) and I chose the 32-bit. Then I installed it and everything went working well.

But as mentioned on the above link that I need to install the SP1 for SharePoint designer (*Please make sure your installation of SharePoint Designer is up to date by using Microsoft Update, or installing Service Pack 1 from here*). So I download the SP1 from the following [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2817441) and I chose the 32-bit.
But the problem I faced is that when I tried to install the SP1 i got this error:

[image]

Can anyone advice on this please? Why can't I apply the SP1 for SharePoint designer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Command Prompt use below command

```
C:\path_of_download_directory\spdsp2013-kb2817441-fullfile-x86-en-us.exe  PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1
```

Comment: what will this do exactly ?

Comment: It bypasses the detection check.. This is the recommended solution from Microsoft

Comment: just to understand my problem ,, so what is causing the error i am getting ?

Comment: I think your system might have an office component which has a higher build version number

Comment: so is running this command will cause any problem to existing office products or will  down size the version of the other office products? or it is safe to run this command ?

Comment: The script will simply bypass the check.. and it will install required files that comes as part of the install.. I saw this command on microsoft blog site..

Comment: Now i run the command, then i got the SPD installation wizard and i click on ok .. and after less than 1 minute i got a confirmation that the installation is completed.. i thought the process should take longer.. so how i can verify that the SP1 is installed successfully ?